# Hello everyone I'm trying to check if my proof for this statement about connectedness in topological spaces is correct.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are connected, then $X \times Y$ is connected.

Proof.  Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are connected, and $X \times Y$ is not. Then there exists a proper subset $A$, i.e., $A \subset X \times Y$ such that $\text{Bdry}(A) = \emptyset$ that means, for $A= U \times V$ we get that $\left[ U \times V \right]^{\text{open}} \subseteq X \times Y$ and $\left[ U \times V \right]^{\text{closed}} \subseteq X \times Y$ then we found $U^{\text{open}} \subseteq X$, $U^{\text{closed}} \subseteq X$, and $V^{\text{open}} \subseteq Y$, $V^{\text{closed}} \subseteq Y$,  meaning that $U$ and $V$ are clopen for $X$ and $Y$ respectively, but that is not possible since by assumption $X$ and $Y$ are connected, hence the only clopen sets are the whole space and the empty set.

That is what I did so far.

Comment: For one thing, why should $A$ be a product of sets?

Comment: That's my doubt I don't know how could the open or closed sets be in the product $X \times Y$ I assumed that because these are the basic open sets.

Comment: So every open/closed set in $\Bbb R^2$ is an open/closed rectangle?

Comment: Thanks, I will make the corrections of that part, but is there a chance to proof the statement with this Boundary argument? I know there are some other ways like using the fact that a space is connected iif there exists a continous consant map $f: X \longrightarrow \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace_{\tau_{disc}}$, but I would really like to explore this one.

Comment: The proof I know is based on a completely different approach. I cannot see how this one can work.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is works, but there are more direct proofs. As connectedness is a topological property, it's preserved by homeomorphism. It would be a far better approach to try to prove this statement by using a map which is a homeomorphism between $Y$ and some $\{x_1\} \times Y$ and between $X$ and some $X \times \{y_2\}$.